# Mocking axios get and post in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I'm trying to mock axios `get` and `post` in `jest`. So far this is my code:

```
//...
jest.mock('axios');
axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: '' });
axios.post.mockResolvedValue(null);

test('should match snapshot', () => {
  const { asFragment } = renderComponent();
  expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
//...
```

As far as I see, it's exactly the same as in the docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/25.x/mock-functions#mocking-modules)

Exact example:

```
// users.test.js
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './users';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const users = [{name: 'Bob'}];
  const resp = {data: users};
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
  // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

  return Users.all().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(users));
});
```

And I'm getting `TypeError: _axios.axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this seems to do the trick

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.mock('axios');
  axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: '' });
  axios.post = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('');
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for posting an answer. Sometimes people on StackOverflow download self-answered questions but you genuinely saved me a bunch of time.